# What should our tag wikis say, and does anybody want to help write them?

Tags: discussion, tags

Looking at the first page of our [tags](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/2005/73), I see that there are a lot of unexplained tags.  That's probably ok for some, such as [jesus](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jesus), but for others ([sensus-plenior](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensus-plenior) and [history](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), for instance) that's not so good.

I've done a few today, but there are some tags I don't feel qualified to describe and I probably shouldn't spend a lot of time on the project.  So I was wondering if anyone would like to help out on this project?

Besides the [general advice](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/), does anyone have any suggestion about how we should write the tag wikis for our site?  Specifically:

- What should be in the wikis for our many book tags?  A synopsis of the book?  Nothing, because our users are presumed to be fluent in biblical texts?  Cross-references to related tags that might be overlooked (e.g. in [genesis](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genesis), cross-reference [creation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creation), [antediluvian](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antediluvian), etc)?
- What about the person-name tags, like [jesus](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jesus), [mary](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mary), [moses](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moses), etc?
- The tags for individual hermeneutic methods might be the most important to have wikis for, but may also be the least clear about what we should cover.

Per the linked blog post, tag wikis for well-known people/concepts should focus on how to use the tag *on our site*, but what does that look like?

Comment: Some sites use the tags on the faq [like this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) - if we choose to do something like that, it becomes especially important to have a clear concise wiki summary.

Comment: @JackDouglas ooh, I like that

Answer (score 2):

It seemed the easiest thing to do to get the discussion moving was create a sample format. This one is a proposal for book type tags. I've tried to use Genesis as an example where possible, but because our question set isn't quite up to the vision, I've incorporated questions from other books, but hopefully you get the idea.

I'm not saying that all book tag wikis need to follow this exact format. I'm just proposing it as a starting point for discussing what kinds of things might end up in one.

---

## Genesis

Brief blurb about book.

#### You should tag questions [genesis](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genesis) when:

- You have a question about a passage in Genesis
- You have a question comparing another text to one in Genesis
- You have a question about the book of Genesis (e.g. authorship)

#### Not to be confused with other potential "Genesis" related tags:

- [john-the-baptist](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-the-baptist)—The prophetic figure described in the gospels as Jesus' forerunner.
- [john-zebedee](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-zebedee)—One of Jesus 12 chosen disciples.
- [1-john](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1-john)—The epistle titled 1st John.
- [2-john](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2-john)—The epistle titled 2nd John.
- [3-john](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3-john)—The epistle titled 3rd John.

#### When asking a question about Genesis, you should:

Instructions go here, like a nice bullet list.

#### Questions of Composition

- [Who wrote Genesis?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1255/33)
- [When was Daniel written?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/107/33)
- [For whom was Ephesians written?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1176/33)

#### Frequently Asked Questions

- List of 5-10 important questions on Genesis
- [Does Genesis's creation account depict creation “ex nihilo”?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/1230/33)
- etc...

#### Bibliography

- Hamilton, Victor P (1990). The Book of Genesis: Chapters 1–17. Eerdmans. ISBN 9780802825216.
- Hamilton, Victor P (1995). The Book of Genesis: Chapters 18–50. Eerdmans. ISBN 9780802823090.
- Wenham, Gordon (2003). "Genesis". In James D. G. Dunn, John William Rogerson. Eerdmans Bible Commentary. Eerdmans. ISBN 9780802837110.
- etc...

#### Helpful Resources

- Link to online texts
- Links to online commentaries

Comment: @GoneQuiet Thanks for the feedback. I updated that section with some ideas and I added another section as well based on the [tag:john] tag wiki that lists potentially confusing tags.