# A roadmap to Biblical Studies

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Recently, Soldarnal suggested a name for our site that I quite like: [Biblical Studies](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/531/68).  It seems that Stack Exchange would be willing to entertain a name change, if we think it's a pressing issue.  Over the last few months, I think we've tackled a number of meta-questions that have clarified our site's aims and policies, but in all honesty there are a number still outstanding.  It seems that we ought not worry about our name until we have settled disagreements concerning what our name represents.  I've compiled a list of meta-questions that we need to have some sort of consensus on before we can move ahead.  From a [conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8896816#8896816) with GoneQuiet:

- [What should our title be?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/163/68)

  Even if we *don't* decide to change our name, I think we should settle the questions below.  Currently, BS holds a 7 to 6 lead over BH.
- <strike>[Are questions about the Old Testament from a purely Christian perspective off-topic? [closed]](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/70/68)</strike>

  It's my question and I think it's resolved.  Or rather overtaken by events.  Other questions below replace it.
- <strike>[Why are correct answers sometimes downvoted?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/450/68)</strike>

  The consensus seems to be this is a useful FAQ.  Now linked from "what are we looking for in answers".
- <strike>[How ought we to balance diversity?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/461/68)</strike>

  This question is historically important and fundamentally unresolvable.  It is a sign-post for some key differences that we need to keep in mind as we continue to define the site.  It's not a question we will ever "answer".
- <strike>[Why should one participate in the Biblical Hermeneutics site (is it a viable site)?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/466/68)</strike>

  Like the previous question, this one is important and informs our various discussions about scope, diversity, doctrine, post-modern relativism, etc, but is itself unresolvable.  Visit it from time to time; review the answers there; keep them in mind.  Related: [Friends, we are not Christian](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/441/208).
- <strike>[How should we welcome new users?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/378/68)</strike> - we seem to be doing ok here; our problem is preventing bad answers from new users, not being unwelcoming when they show up
- [Guidelines for editing others' answers?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/417/68) - **not resolved**
- [Various doctrine-related questions.](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=title:doctrine) - will probably never be resolved; our official position is "we are not a Christian site" but that doesn't stop people

---

And some more recent questions:

- <strike>[What are we looking for in answers?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/520/68)</strike>
- <strike>[What does “show your work” mean in the context of exegesis?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/536/68)</strike>
- <strike>[Is postmodern relativism the worldview of this site?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/546/68)</strike> (can't really be *resolved*, only discussed; discussion has happened)
- [What should our tag wikis say, and does anybody want to help write them?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/244/68) - not done but needn't be a blocker
- [What is the ideal end-state for exegesis answers that don't show their work?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/557/68) - **not officially resolved, but with the top answer at +6/-1 and no other close contender, it's probably time to call it and move on**

---

I'd like to encourage you to consider these meta-questions.  If you think we have reached some sort of consensus on a meta-question, feel free to edit this question and `<strike>` it out as I've done above.  Alternatively, if one or more of the questions are irrelevant, we can just delete them.  Finally, if you want to put another item on our stack, go for it.  (The edit history will be available to all, so be prepared to justify your actions!)

Please use answers to record your individual thoughts on this roadmap.  I'm especially interested in how we can promote our site as a place for Biblical Studies and how that would look different (or not!) from what we are now doing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

### In which I perform a U-turn

Looking over the list of meta-questions we'd like to have answered, it seemed like the right time to talk the proposed change with the rest of the [Community Manager team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/1438).  I argued strongly for the change, but the rest of the team convinced me (with effort) that Biblical Hermeneutics is the best name for the site.  Allow me to summarize the reasoning:

1. [Biblical Studies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_studies) and [Biblical Hermeneutics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_hermeneutics) are near synonyms according to Wikipedia:

   > **Biblical studies** is the academic application of a set of diverse disciplines to the study of the Jewish and Christian scriptures, the Bible. For its theory and methods, the field draws on disciplines ranging from archaeology, literary criticism, history, philology, and social sciences.
   >
   > **Biblical hermeneutics** is the study of the principles of interpretation concerning the books of the Bible. It is part of the broader field of hermeneutics which involves the study of principles for the text and includes all forms of communication: verbal and nonverbal.

   Both are academic disciplines and both concentrate on the Bible.  Neither is particularly Christian—indeed hermeneutics specifically includes the Talmud.  (Notice, however, that Biblical studies *applies* other disciplines to the Bible, whereas Biblical hermeneutics concerns *interpretation* of the Bible.)
2. The initial association of Christians to the phrase "Biblical Studies" is to the often undisciplined practice of "Bible Study".  In my experience, such groups devolve into vaguely spiritual "self-help" groups unless the leaders guide with a strong hand.  Most of the Christians I have discussed the matter with have no association to the word "hermeneutics" or only a cloudy idea that it's something professors might be doing.  Searching for "[hermeneutics](https://www.google.com/search?q=hermeneutics&oq=hermeneutics#pws=0&q=hermeneutics)" turns up an article on [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hermeneutics/).  Searching for "[biblical studies](https://www.google.com/search?q=biblical+studies#pws=0&q=biblical+studies)" turns up ads for Christian colleges.

   My [arguments](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/163/68) from the early days of the beta still hold water.  Our current name might require explanation, but it works once people are in the know.  On the other hand, folks might *think* that Biblical Studies means exactly the opposite of what our site is all about.
3. It's better to be a big fish in a small pond than a small fish in a big pond.  We are the third site that Google turns up in a "[biblical hermeneutics](https://www.google.com/search?q=biblical+hermeneutics&pws=0)" search.  We are on [page 2](https://www.google.com/search?q=hermeneutics&safe=active&start=10#pws=0&q=hermeneutics&start=10) for just "hermeneutics".  If we change the name, we should also change the URL, by the way.  Getting rid of the hermeneutics label puts us into a much more crowded (and Christian) population of Bible sites.
4. People don't seem turned off by the name.  Since lots of folks find us via search engines these days, they don't necessarily see our site name before they start reading our questions and answers.  While this does [cause problems](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-before-they-post-bad-answers), it's actually a good sign.  More people are getting our answers (which in my opinion are [far above average](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/619/lets-get-critical-jul-2013-site-self-evaluation) in terms of quality) than competing answers.

What it comes down to is that the name won't change unless there are far more compelling reasons that have not been brought up.  I still like the name "Biblical Studies" (if only because it's easier to spell), but "Biblical Hermeneutics" remains the better choice.  It reflects the academic nature that we strive for and it's unambiguous.  It communicates that we are exclusive in rigour, but inclusive in *a priori* assumptions.  As the [SEP](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hermeneutics/) says (only slightly taken out of context):

> Hermeneutics turns philosophical.

Comment: I think you'll find some of us are [already agreeable](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/166/36) to this verdict ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we need to resolve everything on this list before changing the name to **Biblical Studies**. I would simplify this road map to only one question:

- [What should our title be?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163/what-should-our-title-be)

  <s>Biblical Studies currently has the lead.</s>