# What do we want to do with answers that aren't very useful and don't show their work?

Tags: discussion, deletion, post-notices, voting

Let's suppose [we know](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/536/68) what it looks like to "show your work" in an exegesis answer and let's suppose you read an answer that fails to meet the [minimum standard](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/538/68).  If you come back to that answer a few weeks later and it hasn't [been improved](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/417/68), what would action should we take?

---

I'm including two pre-filled options that I think are reasonable.  I [originally considered](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9115184#9115184) a few other ideas and [GoneQuiet helped refine them](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9115759#9115759), but I the options can be boiled down into two philosophies:

- Judge answers on their own.
- Judge answers in the context of the other answers to the question.

Comment: @GoneQuiet: Well, I don't think we can tell if you vote up  one and vote down the other _unless you tell us_!  If I could vote, I'd probably only vote on one of the answers.  But if you strongly favor one and strongly oppose the other, I think it's fine to vote that way.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a 'what do we do about answers that don't show their work' or a precursor to that question?

Comment: @JackDouglas: It's really a precursor.  I'm trying to do the "vision thing".  But I don't think it will require much imagination to see how we get where we want to go once we know the goal.

Comment: @GoneQuiet Re flag: I decided against tagging faq on the basis that this isn't really written in a way that would make any sense to somebody new to the site hitting this issue for the first time. Its more of an advanced user discussion about moderation.

Answer (score 7):

**Judge answers on their own.**

Such answers should either be:

- Downvoted with a score of -3 or less (so that they are greyed out) with explanatory comments.

`or`

- Annotated with a post notice.

`or`

- Deleted.

Answer (score -2):

**Judge answers in the context of the other answers to the question.**

Such answers should either be:

- Buried under one or more clearly superior answers

`or`

- Have a score of 0 or less with explanatory comments.

`or`

- Annotated with a post notice.

`or`

- Deleted.