# Specific answer that doesn't show any work

Tags: discussion, support, answers, not-an-answer, flagging

Recently flagged [this post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/57032/27054) as not an answer which basically has

> "In the song, there is more detail. Was Sisera able to get up after the initial blow? Or is this some poetic add-on to spice up the event?"
>
> I don't think so, I think he really drank the milk and fell asleep, that's when Jael killed him.

Given that the initial block of text is from the question, the only thing the user wrote was

> I don't think so, I think he really drank the milk and fell asleep, that's when Jael killed him.

Personally, I think **this is a comment** and **not an answer** hence the flag. In order for it to be an answer, it must show more content than just one line without any references (aka more effort).

Back in 2013 [this would have been an acceptable flag](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/558/27054).

How to proceed in such cases?

Comment: You're right, so I added a post notice to it, and it may be deleted in the future.

Comment: Thank you @curiousdannii.

Comment: @curiousdannii I dont understand... how is that I flagged again as VLQ and it was declined by a moderator even though you just mentioned that I was right? (in other words, the post still exists)